# AWS Setting instance to use domain from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

We're transitioning between accounts and we have an app on our new account but we want to use the domain from our old account. We plan on shutting off the old account soon and transitioning everything over, but there's services running on the old account so we can't do that yet.

The best idea I had is to try and use RAM and share the VPC instance and then set a new load balancer in the old account and have a DNS entry in Route 53 pointing to that load balancer. Whenever I try to share the resource it's giving me and error that I don't have permissions to share with an external account, even when I use a root account, I've tried writing policies to give myself permissions but that didn't work either, but I could have written the permissions incorrectly.

Would anyone know how to fix this permissions issue? Or know of a better way to achieve my goal?

Let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting this right; Maybe you can just create on your old account's Route53 public hosted zone a CNAME record (if you have a load balancer on your new account) or an A record for the instance on your new account. Just don't use the Alias functionality from Route53 as you wont find the resources from the new account.